# Popen.communicate escapes a string I send to stdin

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to spawn a process using `Popen` and send it a particular string to its `stdin`.

I have:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
pipe.communicate( my_stdin_str.encode(encoding='ascii') )
pipe.stdin.close()
```

However, the second line actually escapes the whitespace in `my_stdin_str`. For example, if I have:

```
my_stdin_str="This is a string"
```

The process will see:

```
This\ is\ a\ string
```

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: If I run your code with `cmd='cat'` on `bash`, `cat` doesn't output any `\ `. What shell are you using? Can you tell us what `cmd` is? Did @BrianCain's suggestion fix the problem?

Comment: are you sure your program doesn't just print an escaped version of the string? I'm quite sure python doesn't do any escaping here.

Comment: you don't need `pipe.stdin.close()`. `pipe.communicate()` should close stdin by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you know you need it for some reason, don't run with "shell=True" in general (which, without testing, sounds like what's going on here).

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce it on Ubuntu:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

shell_cmd = "perl -pE's/.\K/-/g'"
p = Popen(shell_cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate("This $PATH is a string".encode('ascii'))
```

In this case `shell=True` is unnecessary:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cmd = ["perl", "-pE" , "s/.\K/-/g"]
p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate("This $PATH is a string".encode('ascii'))
```

Both produce the same output:

```
T-h-i-s- -$-P-A-T-H- -i-s- -a- -s-t-r-i-n-g-
```